# QKeySequence::Backspace

Tags: macos, qt, keyboard-shortcuts, qt5, qkeysequence

In Qt, `QKeySequence::Delete` corresponds to `deleteForward:` message in MacOS.

What is the Qt equivalent of `deleteBackward:` from MacOS? If there is no such thing, how to capture the `deleteBackward:` event in Qt?

Qt documentation on key sequences does not mention this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qkeysequence.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QKeySequence has a constructor that takes key codes:

```
QKeySequence::QKeySequence(int k1, int k2 = 0, int k3 = 0, int k4 = 0)
```

For **deleteBackward:** you would use the **Qt::Key_Backspace** key code. If you for example whish to create a shortcut for a QAction object:

```
myAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Backspace));
```

or simply:

```
myAction->setShortcut(Qt::Key_Backspace);
```